# XSLT transform merging values

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have an XML input document that is formatted as follows:

```
<Label>
    <Person>
        <Hash>12345</Hash>
        <Id>123123</Id>
        <Firstname>John</Firstname>
        <Lastname>Doe</Lastname>
        <Category>Business</Category>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Hash>12345</Hash>
        <Id>456789<Id>
        <Fistname>John</Firstname>
        <Lastname>Doe</Lastname>
        <Category>Information</Category>
    </Person>
</Label>
```

I want to merge all sub nodes from the Person which results in the following output document:

```
<Label>
    <Person>
        <Hash>12345</Hash>
        <Id>123123, 456789</Id>
        <Firstname>John</Firstname>
        <Lastname>Doe</Lastname>
        <Category>Business, Information</Category>
    <Person>
</Label>
```

So actually merging all nodes from the Person to one. Preferably merging the same values to one value but this is no must. So also the following transformation is acceptable:

```
<Label>
    <Person>
        <Hash>12345, 12345</Hash>
        <Id>123123, 456789</Id>
        <Firstname>John, John</Firstname>
        <Lastname>Doe, Doe</Lastname>
        <Category>Business, Information</Category>
    <Person>
</Label>
```

Any suggestion on how to accomplish this is more then welcome!

Transformation preferably in xslt 1.0

Comment: Is the merging depending on any key value in the `Person` elements? Or are you just wanting to merge all `Person` elements together?

Comment: Just want to merge all elements together, so no key value

Answer (score 0):

To make looking up the field values slightly simpler, you could define a key.

```
  <xsl:key name="field" match="Person/*" use="local-name()" />
```

Then, you just need to select the child nodes of the first `Person` element, and for each one use the key to key the values...

```
  <xsl:for-each select="key('field', local-name())">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Try this XSLT, which leaves the duplicates in

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="field" match="Person/*" use="local-name()" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Person[1]/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('field', local-name())">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Person[position() > 1]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you did want to remove duplicates, you would need to use Muenchian Grouping. These means declaring a second key

```
 <xsl:key name="fieldAndValue" match="Person/*" use="concat(local-name(), ':', .)" />
```

And to get the distinct values, change the `xsl:for-each` like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('field', local-name())[generate-id() = generate-id(key('fieldAndValue', concat(local-name(), ':', .))[1])]">
```

Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:key name="field" match="Person/*" use="local-name()" />
  <xsl:key name="fieldAndValue" match="Person/*" use="concat(local-name(), ':', .)" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Person[1]/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('field', local-name())[generate-id() = generate-id(key('fieldAndValue', concat(local-name(), ':', .))[1])]">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Person[position() > 1]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, if you could use XSLT 2.0, you could it much simpler...

```
<xsl:template match="Person[1]/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(key('field', local-name()))" separator=", " />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**EDIT**: If you can't use `xsl:key` then change the `xsl:for-each` (in the first XSLT that does not remove duplicates) to this....

```
 <xsl:for-each select="//Person/*[local-name() = local-name(current())]">
```

This retains the duplicates. Removing duplicates without a key is possible, but probably too much trouble than its worth....

Comment: It works but.... In Altova XMLSpy it transforms but in the final product it appears i can not use a "key". I have been trying to change the xslt but no luck up till now; keep struggeling with the select in the match="Person[1]/*" to write it without key. So hoppefully you have a suggestion for this.

Comment: I've made an edit to my question to show how to do it without a key, but you should really be looking to upgrade your "final product" so that it does allow keys. `xsl:key` has been around since the first official release of XSLT 1.0 back in 1999, so whatever you are using must be rather old.....

Comment: Thanks for all updates! I even got it working with the key value (made some mistakes on first hand). It all works, very good job!

Comment: In the xslt which removes the duplicates if i wanted to exclude some of the sub nodes from merging even if the values are the same how to exclude them? In other words make a selection on the subnode (for example i always want to have the list of values of the Hash node even if they are the same).

Comment: If I have understood correctly, you could change the `xsl:for-each` to something like.. `<xsl:for-each select="key('field', local-name())[local-name() = 'Hash' or local-name() = 'Id' or generate-id() = generate-id(key('fieldAndValue', concat(local-name(), ':', .))[1])]">`

Comment: Thanks [Tim C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7585/tim-c) for this update, exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = require('xml-js')

//let xml = '**your xml string**'
let xml = '<Label> <Person> <Hash>12345</Hash>        <Id>123123</Id>        <Firstname>John</Firstname>        <Lastname>Doe</Lastname>        <Category>Business</Category>    </Person>    <Person>        <Hash>12345</Hash>        <Id>456789</Id>        <Firstname>John</Firstname>        <Lastname>Doe</Lastname>       <Category>Information</Category>    </Person></Label>'

jd = JSON.parse(x.xml2json(xml, {compact:true})) //converting xml to json

//Putting all values in first index

jd.Label.Person[0].Hash._text = jd.Label.Person.map((ele)=>{return ele.Hash._text}).join(",")

jd.Label.Person[0].Id._text = jd.Label.Person.map((ele)=>{return ele.Id._text}).join(",")

jd.Label.Person[0].Firstname._text = jd.Label.Person.map((ele)=>{return ele.Firstname._text}).join(",")

jd.Label.Person[0].Lastname._text = jd.Label.Person.map((ele)=>{return ele.Lastname._text}).join(",")

jd.Label.Person[0].Category._text = jd.Label.Person.map((ele)=>{return ele.Category._text}).join(",")

let options = {compact: true, ignoreComment: true};

let all = jd.Label.Person[0]

jd.Label.Person=[] //Deleting all the records

jd.Label.Person.push(all) //Inserting single record contains all

let newXml = x.json2xml(jd, options) //json to xml again

console.log(newXml)
//newXml is the new generated xml
```

Comment: tanmay-shrivastava thanks for your solution but i was looking for a solution in xslt. Nevertheless thanks for looking into this!